# What wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO 
product_search_table (id, score) 
VALUES (
SELECT product_id, 50 FROM cart_product WHERE product_id = 555
)
```

Is giving me an error. What am I doing wrong?

555 is going to be replaced with a variable.

Comment: Just for my peace of soul: Was this just a minimized example? Because the subquery is totally unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Bobby I have a temporary table containing search results from an algorithm. The algorithm does not check to see if the product id matches the search terms. So with the code above, if the search query is the product id of a product, it will insert the temporary table with the product from the original table; with a high relevance score. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using incorrect syntax for an INSERT...SELECT query.

Here's how you'd do it properly:

```
INSERT INTO product_search_table (id, score) 
SELECT product_id, 50 FROM cart_product WHERE product_id = 555
```

More information: [MySQL 5.1 Reference: INSERT..SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Nice to see that we're all on the same page. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
INSERT INTO 
product_search_table (id, score) 
SELECT product_id, 50 FROM cart_product WHERE product_id = 555
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a syntax issue.  VALUES doesn't belong in this type of query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: And, here I was surprised that no one had answered this question yet...

Answer (score 1):

Brackets around the select look suspect - as does the VALUES.  Try:

```
INSERT INTO product_search_table (id, score) 
SELECT product_id, 50 FROM cart_product WHERE product_id = 555
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO product_search_table 
(id, score) 
SELECT product_id, 50 
  FROM cart_product 
 WHERE product_id = 555
```

When using a SELECT statement in an INSERT statement, you don't use the VALUES keyword or enclose the SELECT in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that with the VALUES.

for example:

```
INSERT INTO 
 product_search_table (id, score) 
SELECT product_id,50 FROM cart_product WHERE product_id = 555
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the subquery could return multiple rows (in theory). So how could multiple rows fit into a single field? You could try to make sure the queried data is a scalar value.

(I'm also not too sure about the second field/the 50 value).

edit: VALUES is used in insert statements people. See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

edit2: You're only selecting data for the first column, where is the data for the second column?

Comment: VALUES is sometimes used for INSERT, but not in this case.